# Maven <LocalRepository> tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml

By default Maven downloads all the dependencies to ${user.home}/.m2/repository/ dirctory.

I read about the tag LocalRepository which allows us to change the default path. I tried adding this tag add different locations in pom.xml file. But I could not find its exact location in the pom.xml file.

Do I need to put it in settings.xml or pom.xml?

can you please help me to add this tag to correct position in xml file.

`<settings>
    <localRepository>
        D:\Ravindra\Projects\MavenSpringJar\
    </localRepository>
</settings>`

Is it inside `<project>`,`<dependencies>`,`<dependency>` tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [localRepository](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) tag is only allowed within the `setttings.xml` file but **not** in the [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) file.